# Which alloys are used in the Canon EF 300mm f/2.8L?

Tags: lens, canon

Can anyone confirm that which alloys of magnesium and titanium are used by Canon for the construction of parts in the EF 300mm f/2.8L lens?

Comment: Probably only Canon as I doubt many people will have bought a lens and subjected it to metallurgical analysis. Why is this important to you?

Comment: I am designing a system which will employ his camera exposed at around 80-120C..

Comment: For insitu imaging of a reaction vessel

Comment: In that situation the ONLY way to go would be a purpose built (not necessarily custom) camera/insulated case. There will be no DSLRs/lenses made by the big manufacturers that you can buy off the shelf that will handle such extremes.

Comment: A much greater concern than the metals would be the effects of those temperatures on the lubricants, plastic parts, and electronics.

Comment: I'm no engineer, so why can't you install a quartz window and just shoot through that?

Comment: The EF 300mm f/2.8 L also includes fluorite elements that would likely crack in an environment that hot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, Canon don't give operating temperature ranges for their lenses (the [specifications](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/ef_lens_lineup/ef_300mm_f_2_8l_is_ii_usm#Specifications) for the EF 300mm f/2.8L don't mention a temperature range, and neither does the [manual](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/ef_lens_lineup/ef_300mm_f_2_8l_is_ii_usm#BrochuresAndManuals)).

However, even Canon's top-end, built like a tank professional body, the [1D X](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/professional/products/professional_cameras/digital_slr_cameras/eos_1d_x#Specifications) (see the "Operating Environment" section on that page) has an operating range of "only" 0 to 40 °C. While you can probably use it a bit outside that range (plenty of people take photos below freezing), I really wouldn't recommend putting that, and by extension, any other Canon gear, into an environment at 120 °C.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature range you are indicating is way beyond the range of normal operation for such items. The use of fluorite glass elements in such lenses requires the lens to be kept cool to avoid distortion of the arrangement of lens elements. It is part of the reason why the lens is white in colour - it reflects heat rather than absorbs.

You will face many issues at the 80-120 deg C temperature range it's not simply a case of knowing if the metals uses in the lens shell will survive. Canon lenses have many circuit boards with electronic components that will have a high tendency to fail at such temperatures.